# Antenna Trace Impedence matching

Tags: pcb-design, antenna, wireless

I'm developing a wireless board. Datasheet suggests to use an external UFL antenna 50ohm Trace impedance. UFL socket which I selected is having 50 ohm impedance.

So should I offer 50ohm trace impedance along with this?

Comment: You may have to make a impedance matching circuit which matches the thevenin impedance of the entire PCB with the antenna. The impedance matching circuit would make combined thevenin impedance of the PCB and the matching circuit nearly equal to 50 Ohm.  There are calculators to calculate values of capacitors, inductors of a PI or Y matching circuit.